# Fonts not working in chrome extension

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, fonts

I'm 99.9% certain I have this right, but for some reason it isn't working.

I'm making a chrome extension that injects CSS onto a page, and my CSS has been working fine right up until I wanted to change the fonts.

So my manifest has this...

```
"css": ["css/my-custom.css"],
"js": [ "js/jquery.js", "js/my-custom.js", "js/jquery.cookie.js"],
"web_accessible_resources": ["css/my-custom.css", "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf", "images/*.*"]
```

...and my CSS has this...

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'RobotoLtRegular';
    src: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body {
    background: #f1f1f1 !important;
    font-size: 1.2em !important;
    font-family: RobotoLtRegular !important;
}

p {
    font-family: RobotoLtRegular !important;
}
```

...and yet when I reload my extension I don't see the new font. The chrome element inspector also shows that this font should be the one shown on body and p (there are no other fonts overriding RobotoLtRegular.

FYI my fonts are stored in the css directory of the extension, so the path is correct.

I'm at a complete loss.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

UPDATE: If it helps to know, I am loading it as an unpacked extension.

Comment: try adding `format("truetype")` after the font-face url.

Comment: okay but what does the network tab say? As a @font-face that font still needs to be resource-loaded, so is it? Does that extension resource URL work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to add web_accessible_resources into the manifest (works for manifest version 2):

```
"web_accessible_resources": ["*.ttf" ]
```

To include any other file types you can comma separate them as such:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [ "*.png", "*.ttf" ]
```

Works perfectly.

Comment: But wait. You already had that in your snippet in the question.

Comment: I think he used the web_accessible_resources key inside the content_scripts key. That is why it did not work initially.

Comment: Doesn't work in manifest v3

Answer (score -2):

fonts -> /fonts/*

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0');
  src: url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.3.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0') format('woff2'), url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0') format('woff'), url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0') format('truetype'), url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.3.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

No other configuration need.